# How to check if html.erb page being used in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

How can I check whether a particular page is being used by rails application ?

Comment: Remove it and then run your system tests should give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Different tools are available there to check the technology use behind an app.
such as [wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com/) or [builtwith](https://builtwith.com/).
you can go there website or you can download there browser extension to check.

Thank you